# Issue with splitting space separated string when string contains double quotes in swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode

Used below code to separate string components with space:

```
let string = "ABC DEF"
let arrayString = string.components(separatedBy: " ")
```

and getting the output `["ABC", "DEF"]` which is correct.

Problem occurs when string contains **Double quotes**. Added the text in `textfield` and using the text of the `textfield` directly to separate it with space.

The string in textfield is `Add sfc""` and using the same code getting the output as `["add", "sfc\"\""]`

Can someone help me why `\` is getting added when string contains double quotes. What can I do to remove it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what happens when you print a string array.

```
print(["", ""])
```

prints

```
["", ""]
```

The array contains two elements that are both empty strings, yet two quote characters - `""` - are printed instead. This is because if the string is printed out literally:

```
[, ]
```

It wouldn't look as "nice". It is less clear that there are two empty strings.

You can think of this like this:

> String arrays are printed as if they are in your code

That's why there are backslashes. Imagine if this is in your code, how would you write a string literal that represents the string `sfc""`? You would write `"sfc\"\"""`, right? So that's what's got printed.

The backslashes aren't actually there, it's just to escape the strings for clarity.

Print each item of the array separately and you see they are gone:

```
print(["", ""][0]) // prints nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

The backslashes are added (virtually) when using `print` or `String(description:` to be able to display double quotes in a literal string. Actually they don't exist.

You can prove it in a Playground.

[image]